# can I say "due to that that ..." if not why?

Tags: conjunctions

"we can't go there due to that that they wont be there."

why are we always to use "due to the fact" cant we just say due to that or due to that that? because sometimes it is not "fact" I give reason for but only a possibility. fact is too certain to me. isn't that so?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Due to the fact that](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-due-to-since-and-as)"  is an idiomatic expression often used to say "because", it does not refer to a specific fact.

> First, let’s disparage all the wordy ways to express the meaning “because.” There are quite a few: “due to the fact that,” “owing to the fact that,” “on account of,” and “on the grounds that,” for example. **If you use “because”** instead of those beasts, **you can save up to four words.**

"Due to that that"  is not used and would probably not be understood.